# How can I make Rubocop treat some errors as warnings instead of errors?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I want to find a way to change a cop from an error to a warning so that I can alter how I deal with the output. I still want the output so that I can examine those situations, but I don't want them to be errors. I can then change the offending code or wrap it in a specific exclusion as needed.

I found the answer this morning and have marked it as such.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want the cop to always be a warning, or only a warning in certain files/classes/methods? Are you saying you want different behavior "in commits" (by which I'm guessing you mean a git pre-commit hook?) than when invoking `rubocop` manually? Perhaps you could edit your question to state your goal more clearly.

Comment: I want that cop to still show up and I want it to be a warning instead of an error. I found my answer right in the documentation. I had missed it like 12x in a row but after a nights rest I found it right away. apologies. I'll put the answer up for the sake of posterity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer turned out to be fairly simple. you can specify the Severity of a cop:

```
Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 100
  Severity: warning
```

The question ends up being slightly silly because I found the answer right where I'd been looking for it--in the documentation.

Comment: New to me, glad I saw this. I just learned that [the `--fail-level` flag](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#exit-codes) makes use of failure severity.